# Understanding method signature

Tags: java, generics, javadoc, guava, signature

I am trying to understand this method signature:

```
public final <T> FluentIterable<T> transform(Function<? super E,T> function)
```

(taken from http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/FluentIterable.html#transform%28com.google.common.base.Function%29)

I understand that transform returns a `FluentIterable<T>`, but I don't understand what the `<T>` before `FluentIterable<T>` means?

Further, in `Function<? super E,T>`, I understand what `? super E` means, but I can't imagine how the compiler can check this - isn't E unknown at compile time, so how shall the compiler know, if `?` is a supertype of `E`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`<T>` means that this is a method with the generic type parameter `T`. This is similiar to `<T>` after a class name (like `List<T>`), just for methods.

`E` is not unknown at compile time. `E` is also a generic type parameter defined in the class definition:

```
public abstract class FluentIterable<E> extends Object implements Iterable<E>
```

When you create an instance of this class the compiler knows the type of `E`.

Comment: Thank you very much, now I understand the `E` thing. About the first `<T>`, actually it's not really used in the transform method, but in the function class, but it would also be possible to access `<T>` in the transform method, right?

Comment: Yes you would be able to use the type `T` in the method in the same way you could use `E`. If the class would not define `E` the method signature would require `<T, E>` instead of `<T>`.